# ReSharper JSON disable Auto-format

Tags: json, visual-studio, resharper, autoformatting

Is there a way to disable auto-formatting (I assume that ReSharper is responsible for this) when working with json files (but not .cs files!) in VS? Typically when working with appsettings.json. Every time I press Enter (new line), all the white spaces basically disappear. However, when I do the clean-up, the whole file is formatted exactly as I want. This is driving me crazy as I have to do the code clean-up after every change in a json file, so it is readable.

EDIT:
Here are the screenshots:

[image: Before ENTER]

After Enter:

[image: After ENTER]

After clean-up:

[image: After Clean-up]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't completely understand "all the white spaces" disappear. Could you please attach a screenshot with Edit>Advanced>View White Space turned on? Also an image after clean-up would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy I added the screenshots to the question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem.
Which versions of VS and R# do you use?
Do you have other extensions installed?
Could you try to suspend R# (Tools>Options>ReSharper ...>Suspend Now) and see if you can still reproduce it.
If no, R# is really to blame. Resume R# and be sure that you use R#'s code cleanup, not VS's one (try Extensions>ReSharper>Edit>Cleanup Code>Built-in: Full Cleanup). Do you have the same "After clean-up" results?
Also try: go to Extensions>ReSharper>Options>Environment>Editor>Behavior, disable Smart indent on enter and set Auto-insert closing brace to none.