# How do I prevent ReSharper/Rider from auto-formatting certain auto-generated files on save, in a way that will be shared with my team?

Tags: resharper, rider, editorconfig, autoformatting

We use ReSharper/Rider on our .NET 4.7 project, and we have it configured to auto-format the files we edit whenever we save.  This behavior applies to *.cs files, as expected, but it unfortunately *also* applies to some files that the IDE generates(for example: those huge App.Config files with all of those binding redirects).  This is a problem because ReSharper/Rider's formatting rules do not match the format the IDE uses when generating(or automatically modifying) them.  If we ever need to make a manual change to such a file(IE: to solve a merge conflict), then ReSharper/Rider will automatically re-indent everything upon saving, using its own rules.  Then the next time that file gets modified by the IDE(IE: to add a new binding redirect for a newly-installed package), it will be re-indented using the IDE's formatting rules(which are different from ReSharper's).

To avoid this problem, **we would like to exclude certain file types from being auto-formatted by ReSharper/Rider**.  And we'd like this setting to be **automatically shared amongst all of our developers**, similar to how ReSharper/Rider's other settings are(IE: in an editorconfig or a dotsettings file).

I have tried using the setting `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Do not format:`, but that setting does not get shared with my team.  It appears to not be saved in the DotSettings file.
[image: Please don't tell me to change this setting.]

I tried changing the setting specified in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962890/exclude-files-from-solution-wide-code-cleanup-in-resharper), but that didn't work; it *did* get shared with my coworkers, but it didn't have any effect on which files get auto-formatted.  I'm assuming that answer is out-of-date, given that it is from 2015.

I also tried changing `File | Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings | File masks`, but still no luck.  This setting *does* get shared with the rest of the team, but it doesn't prevent any files from being auto-formatted.
[image: Or this one, either.]

I do not believe this question is a duplicate.  To prove that I've done my due diligence, here are the closest questions I've found, and why I don't believe it's a duplicate.

- [How to disable Resharper auto format on save in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091102/how-to-disable-resharper-auto-format-on-save-in-vs2015)

  - This question asks about disabling *all* auto-formatting, which I do not want.
- [Exclude files from solution-wide Code Cleanup in Resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962890/exclude-files-from-solution-wide-code-cleanup-in-resharper)

  - This question is close to what I want, but its answer is either out-of-date or just plain incorrect.
- [Prevent ReSharper from formatting specific code block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177226/prevent-resharper-from-formatting-specific-code-block)

  - I do not want to disable formatting for specific blocks, I want to disable it for all files with a given extension
- [ReSharper JSON disable Auto-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918838/resharper-json-disable-auto-format)

  - The title makes it *sound* like it's asking for exactly what I want, but the content of the post is actually asking to disable auto-format *while typing*, not auto-format *on save*.

Comment: Which file types do you have enabled under _File | Settings | Editor | Code Cleanup_ for your cleanup profile?

Comment: These are all of the boxes that are checked. Sorry for the text wall; StackOverflow apparently doesn't render newlines in comments

* C#

* Visual Basic .NET

* XAML

* ASP.NET/Razor

* CSS

* EditorConfig

* HTML

* HTTP Request

* Handlebars

* Ini

* JSON

* Pug (ex-Jade)

* JavaScript and TypeScript

* Markdown

* Properties

* RELAX-NG

* SQL

* VueExpr

* XML

* YAML

Comment: There's no option to enter custom items; I can only uncheck the ones that are already there.  I tried unchecking XML, since csproj is an XML format, but that didn't affect anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you set "Scheme" to "Project" on the "Code Style" settings page, the value of the "Do not format" setting should be stored in the `.idea` folder of your project and you can share it with other developers if you want to by committing to your repo. Specifically, you want to commit the `.idea\.idea.[Solution_Name]\.idea\codeStyles\Project.xml` file.